# Changing the foreground color of a glyph in a texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Before I dwell into the issue that I'm having, more context is needed. I've written a `FontRenderer` class to render text. Here's how it works: During run-time, if I were to display a string *ABC*, a `GameObject` will be generated to have 3 quads, each with the UV coordinates of every glyph looked up from the atlas texture.

Simple enough. This allows for a single draw call given that the same material is used.

However, if were to add the feature of, say changing the foreground of a specific glyph, how would I approach this problem? I plan to the `\c` escape sequence like so: `\c[A-F]{2}[A-F]{2}[A-F]{2}`.

For example, if I were to color the *A* in *ABC* red and the rest of the string white, I would pass the following string to `FontRenderer`: `"\cFF0000A\cFFFFFFBC"`.

My first thought was to make use of the atlas texture. The idea behind this is to plot a new glyph with the new foreground color and allocate a sprite within the atlas texture. However, this can get quite complex.

My next idea was to use a vertex/fragment shader but I'm unsure if this is possible. Another issue is that if it possible, an instance of the material using my shader would be needed for every rendered string increasing the number of draw calls.

What other way can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest procedural approach would be to change the mainColor of the diffuse shader to color the atlas material. The caveat here is that you can only use the 1 color per instanced material which means that if you wanted A, B and C in your ABC string to each be a different color then you'd need to split them up, causing 3 draw calls instead of one.

Another option would be to use [vertex colors](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh-colors.html) and a shader to procedurally color the material. So when you generate the quads you'd also set the color of each vertex to the color as specified.

Couple of quick resources specific to Unity3D around using shaders to color a material based on vertex color:

- http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/VertexColorUnlit
- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/140613-Vertex-Color-shader

Finally, if either of the above don't suit then I would suggest taking a look at the plugin marketplace for font rendering to either buy or try and then learn from.

Good luck.

Comment: With the second option, I would have to then associate an instance of the material to that string since I would have to modify the parameters in order to set the color of a specific glyph. My guess is that I'd have to pass groups of 4 vertices.

But wouldn't having multiple instances of the same material increase the draw calls?

I haven't looked too much into finding a package, but the unfortunate thing is that the ones I have looked up are closed source.

Also, wouldn't I use the `float4` data type to specify a color with alpha? I don't see how 256-bits are being used.

Comment: Yes my 256bit color limit was false (Old info!), and I've removed it. I've added some links for you to implement a shader that will tint your mesh based on the color of the vertex's. The end result should still be 1 draw call.

Comment: Specifying the vertex colors was the ticket! What's important to note is to make use of `BindChannels` which allows you to specify how to map the vertex data.